# WCF and WebAPI - why one over the other

Tags: wcf, rest, asp.net-web-api

What would be the advantage of using WebAPI over WCF Rest and vice-versa?

If I had to implement a RESTFUL service today, what would be the most preferable method of providing the service?

Answer (score 1):

Simply, because WCF REST is no longer supported. It was there before asp.net offers a decent REST support : It's now the case with Web Api.

One of the main advantage of asp.net Web Api is the similitude with the well known asp.net MVC style programming

WCF was originally created to enable SOAP-based services. WCF REST is a non-trivial mix between two differents worlds : SOAP & REST.

[This question is still pertinent](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/341414/WCF-or-ASP-NET-Web-APIs-My-two-cents-on-the-subjec) when you want to expose service, but for a REST-like api, do not hesitate one second.